# Comfortable Edge Labeling of Undirected Graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm working on a program that finds special [called "interval"] edge-colorings for graphs. Output is as follows:

```
Coloring = {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10 -> 1, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2 -> 2,  
            9 \[UndirectedEdge] 10 -> 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 9 -> 3,  
            2 \[UndirectedEdge] 10 -> 3, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> 4}
```

Now I want to visualize the coloring. I use `EdgeLabels->Coloring`, but it writes the labels in the middle, which is not comfortable, especially in case of symmetric graphs like Complete Graphs. I want to display 2 labels on both ends of each edge.

Right now I can display it only on one end of each edge using the following code:

```
1 \[UndirectedEdge] 10 -> Placed[1, 1/6]
```

and I get the following result:

[image: CompleteGraph[10]]

Documentation suggests to use `Placed[{1,1},{"Start","End"}]` to display 2 labels on two ends. That particular example works, but when I change `"Start"` or `"End"` to `1/6` or `5/6`, no labels are displayed at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may:

```
Show@Table[
  CompleteGraph[3, 
   EdgeLabels -> {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3 -> Placed[1, p]}, 
   ImagePadding -> 10], {p, {1/6, 1/2, 5/6}}]
```

[image]

Comment: didn't know `Show@Table` syntax :)

Comment: @HrantKhachatrian Please be aware that you are building your Graph 3 times. Not a big deal for simple cases, but could be a burden if your Graph is time consuming to build up

Comment: Yes, I guessed that. Thank you. In fact constructing the coloring takes much-much more time than drawing the graph, so it's not a problem at all.

Answer (score 16):

Using `GraphPlot` and a custom `EdgeRenderingFunction`

```
ClearAll[erf];
erf[pos_List, lblcolors_, fontsizes_, linecolor_: Blue] := {linecolor, Line[#], 
 Sequence @@ Table[Inset[Style[Text[#3], lblcolors[[i]], FontSize -> fontsizes[[i]]], 
    pos[[i]] First@# + (1 - pos[[i]]) Last@#, Automatic, Automatic, -Subtract @@ Sort[#],
   Background -> White], {i, 1, Length@pos}]} &
```

Example:

```
edges = {{4 -> 2}, {5 -> 1}, {3 -> 2}, {2 -> 5}, {3 -> 5}};
labelededges = MapIndexed[{First@#1, ToString@First@#2} &, edges];

GraphPlot[labelededges, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> erf[{(5/6), 1/6}, {Green, Red}, {16, 24}],
 PlotStyle -> Thick, VertexLabeling -> True, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]