# How can I get Graph edge labels to parallel an edge line or or follow an edge curve?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, labeling

Edge labels are always rendered horizontally. I would like the label for any straight line edge to be rotated so the bottom of the label's bounding box is coincident with the edge.

There was an older post ([Comfortable Edge Labeling of Undirected Graph](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4863/comfortable-edge-labeling-of-undirected-graph)) that did this using EdgeRenderingFunction, but that has been superseded by EdgeShapeFunction in v12. EdgeShapeFunction does not have access to the label like EdgeRenderingFunction did.

Labels following a curved edge would be a bonus, but just paralleling a tangent somewhere on the edge would suffice.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/192005/58370).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the old `GraphPlot` function in version 12.0.0 using `` GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy ``.

Using a modification of the function `erf` from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4876/125):

```
ClearAll[erf];
erf[pos_List: {.5}, lblcolors_: {Black}, fontsizes_: {12}, 
    linecolor_: Directive[Opacity[0.7], Hue[0.6, 0.7, 0.5]]] := 
   {linecolor, Line[#], 
     Sequence @@ Table[Inset[Style[Text[#3], lblcolors[[i]], 
       FontSize -> fontsizes[[i]]],  
     pos[[i]] First@# + (1 - pos[[i]]) Last@#, {Center, Bottom}, 
     Automatic, -Subtract @@ Sort[#], Background -> None], 
    {i, 1, Length@pos}]} &
```

***Examples:***

```
edges = {{4 -> 2}, {5 -> 1}, {3 -> 2}, {2 -> 5}, {3 -> 5}};
labelededges = MapIndexed[{First@#1, ToString@First@#2} &, edges];

GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy[labelededges, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> erf[], 
 PlotStyle -> Thick, VertexLabeling -> True, 
 ImagePadding -> 20, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1]
labelededges2 = Transpose[{Flatten@edges, StringTake[ RandomWord[5], 4]}];

GraphComputation`GraphPlotLegacy[labelededges2, 
 VertexLabeling -> True, 
 EdgeRenderingFunction -> erf[], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: I've marked this as a solution, but I actually prefer the answer you gave in the link posted by @Rohit in the comment attached to my original question for three reasons: 1) it uses current, not deprecated, functions, 2) it shows the rendering along a curve, 3) it adds the bonus of multiple labels.